# login_enqueue_scripts does not ovewrite the default styles

Tags: wp-login-form

**UPDATED**: The solution is to use [login_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_head) if you need to overwrite – @Jevuska

After updating to WP 4.5 my styles to customize the login page do not overwrite the default WP styles. Here's my code:

```
function my_login_logo() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .login h1 a {
            background-image: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/logo.png);
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            width: 297px;
            height: 64px;
            background-size: 297px;
        }
        .login form {
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        }

        .login label {
          color: #333;
        }

        .login #nav a {
          color: #007CAD;
        }

        body, html {
          background: #fff;
        }
    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
```

Comment: in your case, use `login_head` if you need to overwrite

Comment: Thank you @Jevuska it is exactly what I was looking for. If you want, you can put your comment in an answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*@Kevin*, here a couple options how to overwrite css for login page.

Via [`login_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_enqueue_scripts)

If you use this hook, you need to create css file the same path with `functions.php`, say `login-style.css`, add your code inside, change your property background-image like this `background-image: url(assets/images/logo.png);` ( make sure your path correct ), and add your function with `wp_enqueue_style` in `functions.php`. We use `login` as handle of `login-style.css`, and it will put your css after default WP styles.

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
function my_login_logo()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'login-custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/login-style.css', array('login') );
}
```

Via [`login_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_enqueue_scripts)

Since you have php code inside your css, by use this hook, your inline css code will be put after default WP styles.

```
add_action( 'login_head', 'my_login_logo' );
```